# Meteorjs collection can't be accessed /w async when used with 'export const'

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Okay I am getting into the basics of meteor but I still can't figure what is going on when I define my collections for both server/client using

```
// /lib/collections.js
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

export const Info          = new Mongo.Collection('info');
export const Name          = new Mongo.Collection('name');
export const Dates         = new Mongo.Collection('date');
```

but then I run on my server a `publish`

```
// /server/main.js
Meteor.publish('insertByName', function(query) {
    AsyncAPICall.findName(nameVar, Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(err, names) {
        Name.upsert(query.blob, query.set);
    }));
});
```

I get

> Exception in callback of async function: ReferenceError: Name is not defined

if I edit my collection to

```
// lib/collections.js
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

Info          = new Mongo.Collection('info');
Name          = new Mongo.Collection('name');
Dates         = new Mongo.Collection('date');
```

the upsert works fine. BUT there is a problem with retrieving the data on the client with `subscribe`

I run a

```
// /server/main.js
Meteor.publish('getName_publish', function () {
    return Name.find();
});
```

and

```
// /client/main.js
import {
    Summoners,
    Champions,
    SummonersByName
} from '../lib/collections.js';
import '/client/template/page.js';

// /client/template/page.js
Template.page.onCreated(function pageOnCreated() {
    Meteor.subscribe('getName_publish');
});

Template.page.helpers({
    byname() {
        return Name.find({}, { sort: { updated_at: -1 } }); //{}, { sort: { updated_at: -1 } }
    },
});
```

my object ends up empty.

Basically if there is `export const` I can't `upsert` to the Mongo collection, if there isn't I can't retrieve the records.

**Update** If I use `Name.find().fetch()` in the browser console it returns the object as it's supposed to, but not inside the `Template.page.helpers` or on `Template.page.onCreated`

Comment: You exported that `Name` symbol but forgot to import it inside your `/server/main.js` file. Also modifying your database inside a `publish` function is not a good idea in general. You should probably be using `Meteor.methods` for that.

Comment: Yeah I made some research and I made it work both ways (server / client) without export (it doesn't work with export - no idea why). The issue was my directory structure. I am using that for testing only atm, will switch to methods.